# Remove carriage return(alt+enter) from the end VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Code :

```
Sub removeEndingCarriageReturns()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim inputRange As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set inputRange = Application.Selection
    Set inputRange = Application.InputBox("Range", "Remove Ending Carriage Returns", inputRange.Address, Type:=8)
    For Each Rng In inputRange
        Rng.Value = Replace(Rng.Value, Chr(10), " ")
    Next
End Sub
```

This works perfectly in converting every carriage return into space(" "). What I want is, the code should only convert the carriage return which is at the end. How can I do it to find the ending carriage return?

Selected Range : 
[image]

Cell `B3` and `B6` have carriage returns at the end which I want to remove by using vba code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if the last character is a CR and if so remove it.

```
If Right$(Rng.Value, 1) = Chr(10) Then 
    Rng.Value = Left$(Rng.Value, Len(Rng.Value) - 1)
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use the Like Operator to check that the CR is at the end

```
If Rng Like "*" & Chr(10) Then
    Rng.Value = Replace(Rng.Value, Chr(10), " ")
End If
```